# IQueryable where clause

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Was difficult for me to find a fitting title for this post. But I have the following:

```
IArticleRepository articleRepo = unitOfWork.ArticleRepository;
List<Article> articles = new List<Article>(
                         articleRepo.GetAll()
                         .Where(a => a.Title == searchTerm)
                         //.Where(a => a.Categories.Contains(Category.))
                         .OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate));
```

So some explanation: An `article` has , among other things, a `Title` and a `CreateDate`, and filtering through those is easy. But an `article` also has `categories` associated with it. So an `article` has an `array` property of type `Category`. Type `Category` has a property called `CategoryId` of type `int`.

So in my code where it's commented out, I'm trying to `select` an `article`, which has a `category` associated with it, who's `CategoryId` is equal to.. say `4`.

But I'm finding it quite difficult to express this in my C# syntax. I'm also new to C# so that's not helping either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to write two `Where` clauses; just add another condition to your first `Where`. The second condition should use `Any` function to search for the categories you're looking for.

```
IArticleRepository articleRepo = unitOfWork.ArticleRepository;
List<Article> articles = new List<Article>(
                     articleRepo.GetAll()
                     .Where(a => a.Title == searchTerm &&
                                 a.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryID == 4))
                     .OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate));
```

For multiple categories, suppose you have your CategoryIDs in an `int[]` or `List<int>` named `MyCatIDsList`. They you can change the categories clause in the above query to this:

```
              a.Categories.Any(c => MyCatIDsList.Contains(c.CategoryID))
```

Comment: Getting: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'Article' ... ?

Comment: @DeanGrobler this a typo :-) not need in second `a => `

Comment: You people are too clever :)

Comment: @dotNET as a side note. What if I wanted to search on multiple CategoryIds, so instead of just '4' I have an array of whatever size, that contains a bunch of ints?

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative syntax when using LINQ queries, which is more like SQL. The code above is correct, but you may find this version more concise:

```
int categoryId = 4
IArticleRepository articleRepo = unitOfWork.ArticleRepository;
var articlesQuery = from article in articleRepo.GetAll()
                    from category in article.Categories

                    where category.CategoryId == categoryId
                    where article.Title == searchTerm
                    orderby article.CreatedDate descending

                    select article

List<Article> articles = articlesQuery.ToList();
```

Or its more common to do these all together in one step:

```
int categoryId = 4
List<Article> articles =   (   
                             from article in articleRepo.GetAll()
                             from category in article.Categories

                             where category.CategoryId == categoryId
                             where article.Title == searchTerm
                             orderby article.CreatedDate descending

                             select article
                           ).ToList()
```

Comment: `article` has one-to-many relation with `category`, as evident from the OP, so this solution will most likely not work.

Comment: Although it's some real nice clean looking code, dotNET is correct by what he said here above. It's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new list and you can use several where expressions in one Where clause. Can you try the following code:

```
List<Article> articles = articleRepo.GetAll()
                     .Where(a => a.Title == searchTerm && a.Categories.Contains(Category)).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate)).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't compile unless you add .ToList()

Comment: Oh yes, you are true.

Comment: "you are true" is so very *developer*! :)

Comment: That was very "Exception"al :)